# Alternative to wiremock for spring boot app integration testing

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing

Currently I have one of the spring boot apps which is using wiremock for mocking the external services dependency in integration testing. However I have experienced that those tests are very fragile and unpredictable and takes lot of time to execute.

I want to know if there are better ways to mock external services dependency for integration testing purposes in spring boot application ?